# Show more than one row MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

My coding id for search results.

I am showing results from a search, at the moment it will only show the first result, how can i make this show all results that match the search?

Here is my code

```
      <?php
    $name=$_GET["q"];
    if ($name<=""){echo( "");  
     }
     else
     {
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","cl49-XXX","XXX");
    if (!$con) 
      {
       die('Could not connect: line 513 ' . mysql_error());
       }
    mysql_select_db("cl49-xxx", $con)or die( "Unable to select database");
    $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE `prodname` LIKE '$name%' ")or die('Error: Line 519 ('.mysql_error().')' );

    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $prodID=$row['prodID'];
    $prodname=$row['prodname'];
    $catagory=$row['catagory'];
    }
    echo"
     <div class='row-fluid portfolio-block'>
    <div class='span5 portfolio-text'>
    <img src='userpics/$prodID.jpg' height='80' width='80' alt='' />
    <div class='portfolio-text-info'>
                                                <h4>$prodname</h4>
    <p></p>
        </div>
        </div>
    <div class='span5'>
<div class='portfolio-info'>
Product ID
                                                <span>$prodID</span>
        </div>
  <div class='portfolio-info'>
                                                catagory
                                                <span>$catagory</span>
 </div>
 </div>
  <div class='span2 portfolio-btn'>
  <a href='edit_product.php?q=$prodID' class='btn bigicn-only'><span>View</span></a>                                
    </div>
    </div> ";

   ?>
```

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `while` loop like this: `while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { }`

```
<?php
$name = $_GET["q"];
if ($name <= "") {
  echo ("");
}
else {
  $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "cl49-XXX", "XXX");
  if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: line 513 ' . mysql_error());
  }
  mysql_select_db("cl49-xxx", $con) or die("Unable to select database");
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE `prodname` LIKE '$name%' ") or die('Error: Line 519 (' . mysql_error() . ')');
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $prodID = $row['prodID'];
    $prodname = $row['prodname'];
    $catagory = $row['catagory'];
    echo "
     <div class='row-fluid portfolio-block'>
    <div class='span5 portfolio-text'>
    <img src='userpics/$prodID.jpg' height='80' width='80' alt='' />
    <div class='portfolio-text-info'>
                                                <h4>$prodname</h4>
    <p></p>
        </div>
        </div>
    <div class='span5'>
<div class='portfolio-info'>
Product ID
                                                <span>$prodID</span>
        </div>
  <div class='portfolio-info'>
                                                catagory
                                                <span>$catagory</span>
 </div>
 </div>
  <div class='span2 portfolio-btn'>
  <a href='edit_product.php?q=$prodID' class='btn bigicn-only'><span>View</span></a>
    </div>
    </div> ";
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: @Shane I was checking now what the problem ;)

Answer (score 2):

you have to loop through you results like this:

```
while($row = mysel_fetch_array($result)){
$prodID = $row['prodID'];
$prodname = $row['prodname'];
$catagory = $row['catagory'];
echo "
<div class='row-fluid portfolio-block'>
   <div class='span5 portfolio-text'>
    <img src='userpics/$prodID.jpg' height='80' width='80' alt='' />
    <div class='portfolio-text-info'>
        <h4>$prodname</h4>
        <p></p>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class='span5'>
    <div class='portfolio-info'>
        Product ID
        <span>$prodID</span>
    </div>
    <div class='portfolio-info'>
        catagory
        <span>$catagory</span>
    </div>
 </div>
 <div class='span2 portfolio-btn'>
    <a href='edit_product.php?q=$prodID' class='btn bigicn-only'><span>View</span></a>
 </div>
</div> ";
}
```

Still this is quite messy, and even worse, [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php). Try to switch to mysqli_* functions or PDO. And think about capsulating code in classes or at least functions to clean up things a little bit.

Answer (score 2):

first you need to find how many lines of code are there in $result...`$numberofrows = mysql_num_rows($result)` and then make cycle, for example `for ($i =0; $i<$numberofrows; $i++)` and then you need to echo all the rows you get in the cycle

by the way...using function mysql_* is deprecated, so you rather use PDO or mysqli...

Answer (score 0):

Do your $row assignment in a while block, something like this

```
<?php
$name=$_GET["q"];
if ($name<=""){echo( "");  
 }else {

 $con = mysql_connect("localhost","cl49-XXX","XXX");
    if (!$con) {
       die('Could not connect: line 513 ' . mysql_error());
       }

    mysql_select_db("cl49-xxx", $con)or die( "Unable to select database");
    $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE `prodname` LIKE '$name%' ")or die('Error: Line 519 ('.mysql_error().')' );

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $prodID=$row['prodID'];
        $prodname=$row['prodname'];
        $catagory=$row['catagory'];

        echo"
             <div class='row-fluid portfolio-block'>
            <div class='span5 portfolio-text'>
            <img src='userpics/$prodID.jpg' height='80' width='80' alt='' />
            <div class='portfolio-text-info'>
                                                        <h4>$prodname</h4>
            <p></p>
                </div>
                </div>
            <div class='span5'>
            <div class='portfolio-info'>
            Product ID
                                                            <span>$prodID</span>
                    </div>
              <div class='portfolio-info'>
                                                            catagory
                                                            <span>$catagory</span>
             </div>
             </div>
              <div class='span2 portfolio-btn'>
              <a href='edit_product.php?q=$prodID' class='btn bigicn-only'><span>View</span></a>                                
                </div>
                </div> ";
    }
}

?>
```